# Can a Raspberry Pi be a viable solution for a small company VPN server?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, raspbian

I would like to implement an OpenVPN server for a small business (~10 people).
Since the company owns NAS that are located in their office, the VPN server should ideally be physically in the same location, and not rely on a cloud solution.

If there is no need to transfer large amount of data through the VPN, but only use it to access some day-to-day files (mostly Word Documents, Excel spreadsheets...), could a decent Rapsberry Pi (e.g: model 4B with 8Gb RAM) be a serious candidate for the job ? Are there any resources giving typical requirements for a VPN server depending on the target trafic ?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Does Raspberry Pi 4 processor support AES-NI instructions?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106474/does-raspberry-pi-4-processor-support-aes-ni-instructions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a network expert, but I would say potentially yes, although also consider looking at [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/) as it is noticeably quicker than things like OpenVPN (in my experience with a pi zero-w at home).

From what I recall, the bottlenecks will be network bandwidth on the Pi, and CPU usage. I don't think RAM plays a big part in the way the packets flow through the network stack, but I may be wrong!

Given the cost, it should be easy to test out and then scale/expand.

Comment: i agree to shaern89, you will run out of cpu, the bandwidth with aldo may be an issue if you dont have a second ethernet card